# Segue not getting selected row number

Tags: swift, segue, ios8, xcode6

I am passing data from a table view controller to a detail view. I tried using `indexPath.row` directly in my `prepareForSegue` method, however it displays an error of

> use of unresolved identifier 'indexPath'

So, after searching the web, I set up the variable `indexOfSelectedPerson` which is assigned the value of `indexPath.row`. The problem when I run the app in the simulator is that prepareForSegue is getting the initial value of `indexOfSelectedPerson` (0), then getting the value of the selected row only after I click it. So, when I hit the back button in the Simulator and select a different row, the detail view shows the info of the row I selected the previous time.

```
import UIKit

class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var people = []
    var indexOfSelectedPerson = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        people = ["Bob", "Doug", "Jill"]
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView?) -> Int {
       return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return people.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {

        let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("personCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.text = "\(people[indexPath.row])"

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)
    {
        indexOfSelectedPerson = indexPath.row
    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {

        if let mySegue = segue.identifier {

            if mySegue == "personDetails" {

                let detailsVC: DetailTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailTableViewController

                detailsVC.selectedPersonName = "\(people[indexOfSelectedPerson])"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, selecting Doug when the app first starts in the simulator displays the details for Bob because `indexPathOfSelectedPerson` is 0. Hitting the back button and then selecting Jill displays the details for Doug because `indexPathOfSelectedPerson` became 1 when I clicked on Doug the previous time. I'm guessing the problem stems from the order in which the methods are called.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The best way to do this kind of thing is not to use the delegate.

### Updated Swift 4+

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let selectedIndex = tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell)
    // Do your stuff with selectedIndex.row as the index
}
```

### Original Answer

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    let selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell)
    // Do your stuff with selectedIndex.row as the index
}
```

Comment: Your added line gave an error in Xcode regarding downcasting AnyObject and suggested changing the line to: let selectedIndex = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as UITableViewCell). That fixed the error.
I changed indexOfSelectedPerson to selectedIndex.row as you said and everything works. Thank you.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. In Xcode 7 (Swift 2.2), you need to force cast the sender to a `UITableViewCell` like so:

`self.tableView.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell)`

Comment: if I have a different types of custom class cells
Then how can I detect type of cell.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 update:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let selectedIndex = tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell)!
    // Do your actual preparing here...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//In didSelectRowAtIndexPath, you use this code:

func tableView(tvMain: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegueName", sender: nil)

    }

//And prepareForSegue to get IndexPath and send your value

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue,
        sender: AnyObject!){

            let indexPath : NSIndexPath = self.yourTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
            //make sure that the segue is going to secondViewController
            let detailsVC = segue.destinationViewController as DetailTableViewController
            detailsVC.selectedPersonName = "\(people[indexPath.row])"

    }
```