# Accessing a Table View IndexPath from prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, nsindexpath

In the prepare segue function in my table view controller, I seem to be getting an error with the index Path.

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "showView"){
        let detailVC: DetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        let indexPath = self.MainTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

        detailVC.test_label.text = names[indexPath.row]
        self.MainTableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: 
    }
}
```

For indexPath.row, it says "BAD_INSTRUCTION" . When I remove the line indexing the names array, it throws the BAD INSTRUCTION error on the line above (the indexPath definition line). When I change the ! After indexPathForSelectedRow to () , it says "Not a function" . I cannot figure out what to do to get the correct index path for the selected row! Anyone know what is going on?

--
The error in the console is: 
        fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Can you show where MainTableView is defined in relation to this class?

Comment: What line is it breaking on?

Comment: @CodeBender       `class MainTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    
                               @IBOutlet var MainTableView: UITableView!`

Comment: @Amloelxer it is breaking on this line  `let indexPath = self.MainTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!`

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24577892/5229157

Comment: @DanielOrmeño I had already looked and tried that solution, but it is still not working for me

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the let indexPath = ... line. See if the MainTableView object is nil or not, since you are likely crashing because it is force unwrapping a nil object. If it is nil, check your connections to your storyboard / xib file.

Comment: @CodeBender Thanks! That solved the problem, it was nil

Comment: Great, I posted it as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place a breakpoint on the `let indexPath = ...` line. See if the `MainTableView` object is nil or not, since you are likely crashing because it is force unwrapping a nil object. If it is nil, check your connections to your storyboard / xib file.

Answer (score 0):

```
Here please find this code. This should work fine.
```

Or change ! to ? in your code. 
//let indexPath = self.MainTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) 

{

 if(segue.identifier == "showView")

    {

   let detailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2
            let path = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
            detailVC.test_label.text = names[path]
     }
}
```